# Django - Filtrar queryset em um form usando um valor presente na view

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Eu estou criando esse site em que o primeiro passo do usuário é criar a empresa que ele trabalha:

```
''''models.py'''
class Empresa(models.Model):
    cnpj = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    nomeFantasia = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    razaoSocial = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=60)

'''forms.py'''
class EmpresaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cnpj = forms.CharField()       
    nomeFantasia = forms.CharField()
    razaoSocial = forms.CharField()
    telefone = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Empresa
        fields = ('cnpj', 'nomeFantasia', 'razaoSocial', 'telefone', 'email')

'''views.py'''
def cadastrarEmpresa(request):
    context = {}
    
    empresa_form = EmpresaForm(request.POST or None)
    if empresa_form.is_valid():
        request.session['cnpj'] = empresa_form.cleaned_data['cnpj']
        obj = empresa_form.save()
        obj.save()
        empresa_form = Empresa()
        return redirect("/accounts/register")

    context['empresa_form'] = empresa_form
    return render(request, 'cadastro-empresa.html', context)
```

Na view está sendo usado session para armazenar o cnpj da empresa, que vai ser usado na segunda parte, que é cadastrar um funcionario que 'administraria' a empresa no site

```
'''models.py'''
class Funcionario(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, max_length=60)
    nome = models.TextField(max_length=35)
    cpf = models.TextField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    '''Campos custom user'''
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, default=None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

'''forms.py'''
class RegistrarionForm(UserCreationForm):
    nome = forms.CharField()
    cpf = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    is_admin = forms.BooleanField(disabled=True, initial=True)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput()
    empresa = forms.ModelChoiceField(disabled=True, queryset=Empresa.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Funcionario
        fields = ("nome", "cpf", "email", "is_admin", "password1", "password2")

'''views.py'''
def register(request):
    context = {}

    empresa_cnpj = request.session.get('cnpj')
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrarionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            cpf = form.cleaned_data.get('cpf')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('senha1')
            funcionario = authenticate(email=email, cpf=cpf,password=raw_password)
            login(request, funcionario)
            return redirect("/home")
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else:
        form = RegistrarionForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

Há uma relação 1:N entre empresa e funcionarios, assim o funcionario só acessa aquilo da empresa em que ele trabalha

A duvida aqui é como passar o `empresa_cnpj` no views.py do funcionario para o

`empresa = forms.ModelChoiceField(disabled=True, queryset=Empresa.objects.all())`
onde seria usado usado como filtro para algo do tipo

`empresa = forms.ModelChoiceField(disabled=True, queryset=Empresa.objects.filter(cnpj=cnpj))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa passar isso para `RegistrarionForm`. Como o CNPJ é único você pode obter o objeto que representa a empresa no seu `view` e associá-lo ao funcionário que você criou com o `Form`.

```
def register(request):
    context = {}

    empresa_cnpj = request.session.get('cnpj')
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrarionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            funcionario = form.save()
            funcionario.empresa = Empresa.objects.get(cnpj=empresa_cnpj)
            funcionario.save()
            login(request, funcionario)
            return redirect("/home")
        
        context['registration_form'] = form
    else:
        form = RegistrarionForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

Uma coisa que eu percebi: você não precisa definir os campos de uma `Form`, se você está usando um `ModelForm` com a classe `Meta` e o atributo `fields` (você já definiu esses campos no próprio `Model`; e é por isso que você está usando o `ModelForm`).
Por fim, eu percebi algumas inconsistências no código, como o padrão de nomenclatura de variáveis e funções, e recomendo a leitura do [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) :)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e dicas, Murilo. Outro erro que eu percebi foi o ```disabled=True``` no campo ```empresa``` dos forms.